# Question regarding the proof of the directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[Proof of the directional derivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mWgl.png)

I have a question regarding this proof. 
I understand the part where they use the chain rule, but how can the point (x,y) be included? The result should just be the partial of the function with respect to x times a , added with the partial of the function with respect to y times b. But instead they have added the point (x,y) in both the partial derivatives, this makes me confused. 
Can anyone explain why the point (x,y) is included?

Answer (score 1):

$f_x a + f_y b$ would not be a fully specified expression, although its often written like it, you actually have to know where to evaluate $f_x$ and $f_y$ to evaluate $g'(z)$. $f_x(x,y)$ in that formula just means evaluate $f_x$ at $(x,y)$.

Edit: If the question is about the full argument list in the chain rule, it goes as follows:
$$g(z) = f(x,y) = f(h(z)) \quad h(z) =\begin{pmatrix} x(z), y(z)\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ \frac{\partial(g(z))}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial (f(h(z)))}{\partial z} = \sum_i \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial h_i } \right|_{h(z)}\left.\frac{\partial h_i }{\partial z}\right|_{z} = \left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{h(z)}\left. \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right|_{z} + \left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{h(z)}\left. \frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right|_{z}   $$ 
Basically you evaluate $f$ in the chain rule at the original point $h(z)$ and the derivative of the inner function at the variable $z$.

OffT: I'm not sure myself about the precedence of arguments in the partial derivative notation, maybe someone else has a reference.

Comment: But I mean, you are not evaluating at any point when applying the chain rule at the beginning? 
It just makes no sense, since the point just pops up from nowhere...